Ensuring that we have symmetrical output in SQL
Say I have a SQL table that looks like this:



Type 1
Type 2
Score




100
200
50


200
100
75


100
500
50



I want to ensure that each (type 1, type 2) is paired and if they aren't paired we can default the score to 0.
Example output:



Type 1
Type 2
Score




100
200
50


200
100
75


100
500
50


500
100
0



Is this possible in SQL?

You can do it without the case.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS scores;
CREATE TABLE scores (Type1 INT, Type2 INT, Score INT);
INSERT INTO scores (Type1, Type2, Score) VALUES (100, 200, 50);
INSERT INTO scores (Type1, Type2, Score) VALUES (200, 100, 75);
INSERT INTO scores (Type1, Type2, Score) VALUES (100, 500, 50);

    SELECT
        s1.Type1,
        s1.Type2,
        s1.Score
    FROM scores s1
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        s2.Type2 AS Type1,
        s2.Type1 AS Type2,
        0 AS Score
    FROM scores s2
    LEFT JOIN scores s3 ON s2.Type2 = s3.Type1 AND s2.Type1 = s3.Type2
    WHERE s3.Type1 IS NULL;


Yes it is possible using SQL and here's the command:
SELECT Type1, Type2, Score 
FROM your_table
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.Type2 AS Type1, t1.Type1 AS Type2, 
    CASE WHEN t2.Type1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE t1.Score END AS Score
FROM your_table t1
LEFT JOIN your_table t2 ON t1.Type2 = t2.Type1 AND t1.Type1 = t2.Type2 
WHERE t2.Type1 IS NULL;


Just UNION the result of the reversed Type_1 and Type_2 fields, the no-paired ones, with a score of 0:
SELECT
  Type_1,
  Type_2,
  Score
FROM mytable

UNION ALL

SELECT
  m1.Type_2,
  m1.Type_1,
  0
FROM mytable m1
LEFT JOIN mytable m2 On m1.Type_1 = m2.Type_2 AND m1.Type_2 = m2.Type_1
WHERE m2.Score is null

see: DBFIDDLE
